# Django: how to create slugs in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i want to create a slug in django, i have used the `slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)`. Now when i create a post with a slug of `learning-to-code` it works, but if i create another post with the same slug `learning-to-code`, it shows an error like `Unique Constraint Failed`. But i want to create posts with the same slug, is there a way to make slugs unique only to the time a post was created?

this is how my model looks

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('userauths.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

How can i go about achieving this?

Comment: Creating posts with the same slug makes not much sense, since a slug is used to determine *what* `Article` is used. If two items have `learning-to-code`, then you can not determine *which* of the two `Article`s is the right one.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique only to time a post was created"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating posts with the same slug makes not much sense, since a slug is used to determine *what* `Article` is used. If two items have `learning-to-code`, then you can not determine *which* of the two `Article`s is the right one.

If your `Article` for example has a `DateField`, you can use this such that is works with both the `date` and the `slug` to determine the `Article`. The easist way to achieve that is likely with the [**`django-autoslug`** package <sup>[PyPi]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/django-autoslug/). This will work with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint), such that the combination of the date and the slug is unique, so:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from django.conf import settings

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique_with=['publish_date'])
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    publish_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The `urls.py` will need to add specifications for the date, so:

```
path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:date>/<slug:slug>', some_view, name='article_detail')
```

then in a `DetailView`, or other views, we can filter on the `QuerySet` with the date:

```
from datetime import date
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            publish_date=date(self.kwargs['year'], self.kwargs['month'], self.kwargs['day'])
        )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: please how do i rewrite this view for function based view and when i try to configure the link that would redirect to the detail page i get this error `Reverse for 'help-detail' with arguments '('', '', datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 12, 1, 3, 44, 313883, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'mollitia-saepe')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['c/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/(?P<date>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']`

Comment: this is how to href is looking `href="{% url 'core:help-detail' h.year h.month h.date h.slug %}"`

Answer (score 2):

If you just like to convert the title into a slug but do not want it as an alternative to the oprimary key, you could use the `slugify` utility of django to convert the title on save and store it in a generic `CharField`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify

```py
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    user = models.ForeignKey('userauths.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use save to check slug before add like:

```
    from django.utils.text import slugify
    import itertools
    # other 
    
    class Article(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey('userauths.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self._state.adding:
                self._generate_slug()
            super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
        def _generate_slug(self):
            if self.slug:
                slug_candidate = slug_original = self.slug
            else:
                # To Generate New Slug If None, You can change
                slug_candidate = slug_original = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
                if not slug_candidate:
                    slug_candidate = slug_original = lambda: random.randint(1, 10000000)
            # Check if Slug exists and add ( learning-to-code-1, learning-to-code-2,................)
            for i in itertools.count(1):
                if not Article.objects.filter(slug=slug_candidate).exists():
                    break
                slug_candidate = '{}-{}'.format(slug_original, i)
    
            self.slug = slug_candidate
```

Comment: i have tried writing the function under the model, but it seem to be doing nothing? is there something else i should do?

Comment: it can be like this

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
```

Add this function to your class

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.slug=slugify(self.slug)
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```